# If $\frac{a(m^n-1)}{n(m-1)}+1$ divides $m^n-1$, then $(n,m,a)=(2,5,1),(2,9,3),(2,13,1)$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $n,m,a$ be integers such that $n\gt 1, m\geq5$ and $a>0$.

Then, is the following true?

> If $\frac{a(m^n-1)}{n(m-1)}+1$ divides $m^n-1$, then $(n,m,a)=(2,5,1),(2,9,3),(2,13,1)$.

With the help of computer, the answer is non-divisible in many cases. But I cannot prove it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a triple $(n,m,a)$ where $n\gt 1,m\ge 5$ and $a\gt 0$ such that $\frac{a(m^n-1)}{n(m-1)}+1$ divides $m^n-1$?

Comment: I am sorry for the state of my problem. While, mathlove‘s@mathlove comment made the question clearly. We know if $(n,m,a)$ satisfies $n=2, m\in\{5,9,13\}, 1\leq a\leq 10^6$, then the answer is divisible. But if $3\leq n \leq 10^4, 1\leq a\leq 10^6$, we cannot find $m$ such that $\frac{a(m^n-1)}{n(m-1)}+1$ divides $m^n-1$.

Comment: @mathlove,you're right. More precisely, provided $\frac{a(m^n-1)}{n(m-1)}+1$ divides $m^n-1$, do we have $n=2, m\in\{5,9,13\}$?.

Comment: A partial result : It can be proven that if $n=2$, then $m=5,9,13$. (I've edited the question. Please check if the edit is correct.)

Comment: @mathlove, Thank you. You are right.

Comment: We have calculated that: Assume $m^n-1=k(\frac{a(m^n-1)}{n(m-1)}+1)$, then we have $n(m-1)=ak+\frac{nk(m-1)}{m^n-1}$. So $m^n-1|nk(m-1)$ and $\frac{m^n-1}{m-1}\leq nk$. Add $k\leq n(m-1)$. We know $\frac{m^n-1}{m-1}\leq nk\leq n^2(m-1)$, which implies that $n=2$or$3$.

Comment: For the case of $n=2$, we know $m\in\{5,9,13\}$.

Comment: That's nice. I've just posted an answer showing that for $n=3$, there is no such $m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got that $n=2$ or $3$, and that for $n=2$, $m\in\{5,9,13\}$.

For $n=3$, $$\frac{m^3-1}{\frac{a(m^3-1)}{3(m-1)}+1}=k\implies (3m-3-ak)(m^2+m+1)=3k$$
where $k$ is a positive integer.

So, writing $s=3m-3-ak$ where $s$ is a positive integer to have
$$s=3m-3-a\cdot\frac{s(m^2+m+1)}{3}\implies asm^2+(as-9)m+as+3s+9=0$$
Considering the discriminant, we get
$$\small (as-9)^2-4as(as+3s+9)\ge 0\implies 27\ge as(as+18+4s)\ge as(as+22)\implies a=s=1$$

Then, the solutions of $m^2-8m+13=0$ are not integers.